# Bit datatype field value 1 is getting converted to -1 automatically in tabular model

Tags: int, bit, data-conversion, ssas-tabular

I have a table in sql server database which has a column "Recovered" of datatype bit. when i imported that table in SSAS tabular model, it was automatically converted into "True/False" data type. I changed it to whole number in column properties and processed that table. It is converting 1 to -1. I want to fix this in tabular model and show it as 1 but not getting how. Any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not rely on implicit data type conversion.

Instead, create a view on top of your SQL table, specifying all the columns you want to import into your Tabular Model, but explicitly converting the bit column to an integer:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[MyView] AS
SELECT
    CONVERT(INT, [Recovered]) AS [Recovered],
    [Column1],
    [Column2],
    ...
FROM [dbo].[MyTable]
```

Then, import that view into your Tabular model instead of the table. SQL Server should properly convert a bit value of 1 to an integer value of 1, which will be retained within the Tabular model.

If you're not allowed to create the view from some reason, you can also put the SELECT query into the partition query of your Tabular model, but having a view is preferable.

Comment: Thanks Dan, That's what i have also done. I cast it to integer in sql server view and used it in tabular model. That solved the problem.